# NestJS route with the same endpoint but with different body

Tags: api, routes, controller, nestjs, endpoint

I want to have a `Post` endpoint but two methods in a controller to fire one of them when an API call is received for that.

The point is that the body specifies which method should be fired!

For example, the following one should fire `/my-endpoint`, but `method A`

```
curl 'http://localhost:8080/my-endpoint' --data-raw $'{ "method": "A" }'
```

And the following one should fire again `/my-endpoint`, but `method B` which has different logic than `method A`

```
curl 'http://localhost:8080/my-endpoint' --data-raw $'{ "method": "B" }'
```

Is there any possibility of implementing this in the NestJS?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a problem with parsing the body in a single controller method and at that point invoking the appropriate method? Perhaps in the service?

Failing this, you could look into versioning, since the endpoint url needs to stay the same you could use either media or header options. https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/versioning#header-versioning-type If the value which dictates which method runs has to be in the body perhaps look at custom versioning.

https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/versioning#custom-versioning-type